# Web API authentication turns request.authentication false

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a project that I created in ASP.NET MVC and now the second part of the work is pass the logic of the ASP.NET MVC application (basically the database) to an ASP.NET Web API and do the connection with them.

The thing is, I already did the connection and I already save values in the Web API database, but a strange thing is happening.

I have markup in my `layout.cs.html` file:

```
<body>
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("MSDiary", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Despesas", "Index", "Despesas")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Rendimentos", "Index", "Rendimentos")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tipos de Despesa", "Index", "TipoDespesas")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tipos de Pagamento", "Index", "TipoPagamentos")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tipos de Rendimento", "Index", "TipoRendimentos")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <footer>
            @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                <p>@Html.Action("_ObtemSaldo", "Home")</p>
            }
        </footer>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

That request is authenticated shows the navbar on the top or not depending if the user is authenticated I cut it off to see if in fact my program is getting the user, and it kinda get the user so the problem is not with the connection, but the request is authenticated don't change in the controller maybe :S

Here is my login controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        try
        {
            var client = WebApiHttpClient.GetClient();
            string username = model.Email;
            string password = model.Password;
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(
            "grant_type=password&username=" + username + "&password=" + password,
            System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("/Token", content);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                TokenResponse tokenResponse =
                await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenResponse>();
                WebApiHttpClient.storeToken(tokenResponse);
                // return Content(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Ocorreu um erro: " + response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return Content("Ocorreu um erro.");
        }
}
```

I already tried with `user.authenticated` still doesn't work if someone can give me a hand I would appreciate it a lot :D

ps: Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, you have an MVC Application and you have passed some logic (database access) to an Web Api project, so when you send a form/request to the server, it will be received by the controller from MVC, and after that the request will be send to the WebApi (at least is what I understood from your code).

Your problem is that the user logs into the application, the MVC Controller goes to the WebApi to authenticate the user and afterwards, even the login and password been correct the MVC (View) still considers that the user is not logged in.

Well, if what I described is correct, seen your code, I would say that the user is indeed being authenticate in the Web Api, however, as the MVC is the direct interface with the user, it is missing set the MVC Application User as authenticated through some authentication method, something like:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
```

It´s worth to say that you would have to store the token (from webapi, after user has been authenticated) so that the nexts requests to the WebApi it considers the user authenticated to that specific token.

Hope I´ve helped.

Regards,

Comment: first thank you for your great explanation, but im kinda newbie and dont understand where should i use that code, as i said if i dont place the request authenticated the user is loged int and i can see his username i just want to display different views depending if the user is autheticate and that i cant do